# I want to remove a paragraph which has specific class (PHP/Regex)

Tags: php, regex

I think this won't count much combinations please, I need to remove from string a paragraph that has specific class (It is consistent)

Example:

```
<p class="special_class">Some content</p>
```

I want to remove the content of every paragraph which has **special_class** only. So I would like to run a regex that returns empty. I do not want to use a parser to do this please, i am using this in very little function inside my script.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to use regex for the HTML parsing. Take a look at [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead to find out the specified and remove it.

If you want to use regex anyway, you could trt this instead:

```
preg_replace('/<p class="special_class">[\w\s]*<\/p>/', '<p class="special_class"></p>');
```

Comment: Will it change the HTML structure of the rest of the document?

Comment: The function is about 4 lines and It is overkill to use parser for this. I need it in regex and I know that it is a bad idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace('%<p\s+class="special_class">.*?</p>%s', '', $subject);
```

should work. It will remove the entire paragraph from the opening to the closing `p` tag. It expects that the `p` tag is properly closed. But you already seem to know about the drawbacks of handling HTML with regexes...